# Check if attribute is provided to shader

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am drawing numerous triangles in the WebGL-based app. Some of these triangles need to be translated, which I plan to do on the shader side. I added `attribute vec3 vTranslate;` to my vertex shader.

I would like to do the following:

```
if(condition_that_vTranslate_is_buffered)
{
    // Do translation
}
```

However, I haven't found a condition that works. While I *could* simply provide `[0, 0, 0]` for each point which is not being translated, I would prefer to not waste that data in the pipeline.

Comment: `condition_that_vTranslate_is_buffered` what does this mean specifically, if one triangle is buffered won't all be? What does 'buffered' mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> While I could simply provide [0, 0, 0] for each point which is not being translated, I would prefer to not waste that data in the pipeline.

The [WebGL 1.0 specification; 5.13.10 Uniforms and attributes](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0.0/#5.13.10) refers to [OpenGL ES Specification 2.0.25](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf#nameddest=section-2.8). See Chaper 2.7 Current Vertex State:

> The initial values for all generic vertex attributes are (0, 0, 0, 1).

This means if the current vertex state of the vertex attribute is disabled (`disableVertexAttribArray`), then the value of the vertex attribute in the vertex shader is (0, 0, 0, 1) respectively (0, 0, 0) for an attribute of type `vec3`. So you don't need to "waste" data and you don't need the specify generic vertex array data initialized with (0, 0, 0). Just disable the vertex array, which causes the same result, an attribute value of (0, 0, 0) in the vertex shader.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question but also the answer and I wasn't able to. What is the goal here? Why not use just `const vec3 zero = vec3(0.);` ?

Comment: But where does that behavior come from? What is `is_buffered` in this context?

Comment: `Some of these triangles need to be translated,` makes little sense to me, since a triangle is three vertices and vertex shaders operate on vertices. `Three vertices belonging to a triangle` need to be translated would make more sense. In which case, using an `attribute` makes the most sense.

Comment: Rather than using an uniform, `uIsBuffered` or such, you're demonstrating that it's possible to disable the array and achieve the same result?

Comment: Anyway it seems like an interesting answer, i just wish if it could be clarified a bit more (both question and answer).

Comment: ahhhhh, i think i get it. `uniform int do_i_have_a_buffer` wouldn't work because the shaders would be different, one without `vTranslate` one with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169696/discussion-between-pailhead-and-rabbid76).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if i understand the question, but based on what I did:

```
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec3 vTranslate;

void main(){

   vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(aPosition.xyz,1.);

   worldPosition.xyz += vTranslate * aPosition.w;

   gl_Position = ndc * view * worldPosition;

}
```

Some places advise against using `if` statements in the shader if they can be done otherwise.